# Laravel 5: Pass data to email view

Tags: php, html, laravel-5

I'm trying to pass some variables to email view.

```
Route::get('sendemail', function () {

    $data = array(
        'code' => "some_code",
    );

    Mail::send('email.verify', $data, function ($message) {

        $message->from('user@gmail.com', 'Learning Laravel');

        $message->to('anotheruser@gmail')->subject('Learning Laravel test email');

    });

    return "Your email has been sent successfully";

});
```

And in the email view I have tried many ways, only `<?php echo $code ?>` works. I wonder what I did wrong.

```
    <div>
    {{$code}}<br>
    {{$data['code']}}<br>
    {{$data["code"]}}<br>

    {{!! $code !!}}<br>
    {{!! $code }}<br>
    {{! $code !}}<br>
    {{! $code }}<br>

    {!! $code !!}<br>
    {!! $code }<br>
    {! $code !}<br>
    {! $code }<br>

    {!!$data['code']}<br>
    {!!$data["code"]}<br>
    <?php echo $code ?><br>
```

Comment: is email view file `.blade.php` extension?

Comment: No. It does not use blade.

Comment: Then you can not print the code via `{{ }}` neither `{!! !!}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @manix
The email view has to have `.blade.php` to use `{{ }}`.